# memcpy rewrite not working

Tags: c, memory-management, memcpy

Hi could anyone explain why this memcpy function does not work ?

```
void    *ft_memcpy(void *dst, const void *src, size_t n)
{    
        while (n--)
                *(char *)dst++ = *(char *)src++;
        return (dst);
}
```

Comment: In what way(s) does this "not work"?

Comment: @andreee actually it is returning a void pointer

Comment: Your `dst++` and `src++` constitutes pointer arithmetic on a `void *`, which is non-standard, although supported as an extension by GNU gcc.

Comment: As far as I can see, the routine does work. However, it possibly works not as _you expect_. What are your expectations? What exactly do you need? For example, what value do you expect the function to return?

Comment: Did you notice that zero is a legal value for `size_t` type...?

Comment: @CiaPan and? It will just **do not** copy anything. Length zero means zero bytes to be copies.

Comment: Two problems: it is not valid C because ++ has higher precedence than cast and you can't use ++ on void pointers. Also, you need to return a pointer to the beginning of the data, not the end of it.

Comment: @Lundin _The __three__ problems in this code ..._  Hang on, I'll come in again.

Comment: @TobySpeight Yeah well, casting away const is another problem, but the whole cast is incorrectly done anyway.

Answer (score 1):

That code shouldn't even compile; it's certainly not conformant C.

Arithmetic on `void` pointers is not defined - what you should do is create `char` pointers from which you can copy.  And remember to return the *beginning* of the destination buffer, not the end:

```
#include <stdlib.h>             /* for size_t */

void *ft_memcpy(void *restrict dst, const void *restrict src, size_t n)
{
    char *d = dst;
    const char *s = src;

    while (n--)
        *d++ = *s++;

    return dst;
}
```

BTW, note that a good compiler is entitled to recognise this copying loop and optimize it into a call of the standard library `memcpy()`.

Comment: No, what should be done is delete the whole thing and use memcpy() directly. Even if you manage to correctly re-implement some standard function it is likely slower than the existing one. And if you fail to correctly re-implement it all sort of fun happens.

Comment: True - but it helps to understand what's wrong with the original, for the times you need something similar but subtly different from a standard function.

Comment: Yeah, but then, as you mentioned (and gcc does that frequently), the compiler just optimizes it back to the standard library memcpy(). Makes writing memcpy() for your own min libc fun,